# Rotating images client side using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, rotation

Is there a good jQuery plug-in to rotate images? Looking for something that is stable.

Answer (score 1):

This looks pretty decent.  I don't have any experience with it though.

[jquery-rotate](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/)

Comment: yeah. i looked at that one. it doesn't look complete yet. i'm looking at something that is more stable.

Answer (score 0):

[Wilq32.RotateImage](http://wilq32.googlepages.com/wilq32.rollimage222)

[Canvas jQuery plugin](http://ajaxian.com/archives/rotate-images-with-canvas-jquery-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

If you can implement a custom solution this it should work fine.

Jquery code -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = $('#container-name').children().length;
    var currentcount = 1;
    var firstimg = $('#container-name a:first');
    var nextimg = $('#container-name a.active').next();
    var activeimg = $('#container-name a.active');

    $(firstimg).delay(2500).fadeOut(2500);

    setInterval(function()
    {
        if (count > currentcount) {
            $(nextimg).fadeIn(2000);
            activeimg.removeClass('active');
            nextimg.addClass('active');
            activeimg = $('#container-name a.active');
            nextimg = nextimg.next();
            currentcount = currentcount + 1;
        } 
        else {
           $(firstimg).fadeIn(2500);
            activeimg.removeClass('active');
            activeimg = firstimg;
            activeimg.addClass('active');
            nextimg = firstimg.next();
            currentcount = 1;
        }
    $(activeimg).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
    }, 5000);
});
```

You will need to add this CSS code to make the transitions.

```
#banners-container a {
    z-index:1;
    display: none;
}

#banners-container a.active {
    z-index: 3;
    display: inline-block;
}

#banners-container a.next {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Hope this helps.